# how to install spark via cloudera tarball?

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

I was wondering how to install spark via cdh spark tarball.spark tarball can be found [here](http://archive-primary.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/)

I can't find any description in CDH document.
I want to try spark standalone and spark on yarn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't install from the tarball. Spark is simply included in the CDH 5.x parcels. You already have it on all your nodes.

Comment: I use CDH4.3 with MRV1 and HDFS2...Does cloudera spark only work with YARN?

Comment: For CDH4.x, it is a separate parcel. See http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/4.8.1/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_spark_installation_standalone.html

Comment: No, for CDH4.x, I *think* that *only* standalone is supported.

Comment: thanks,if I install spark with same cluster running MRV1 and Hdfs2, use standalone model,is there any influence on performances?